# Loading mat accordion dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Based on the JSON structure, I wanted to render the accordion. Below is how it looks like.

```
const area = [{
  type: 'column',
  text: ''
}, {
  type: 'accordion-item',
  text: 'accordion-item 1'
},
{
  type: 'accordion-item',
  text: 'accordion-item 2'
},
{
  type: 'accordion-item',
  text: 'accordion-item 3'
},
{
  type: 'column',
  text: ''
}]
```

So my component html looks like this,

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let area of areas">
  <ng-container *ngIf="area.type === 'accordion-item'; else section">
    <mat-accordion>
      <accordion-item [item]="area"></accordion-item>
    </mat-accordion>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #section></ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

**Accordion Item component**

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
             {{title}}
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I could able to load the accordion component. But the issue is native functionality is not working as expected .

Because for each `accordion-item` I loading this tag `<mat-accordion>` again n again.

So How to avoid this ? Please help

---

**Update.**

After implementing the solution, my template looks like this

```
<mat-accordion>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let area of areas" *ngTemplateOutlet="section; context:area">
    <accordion-item *ngIf="area.type === 'accordion-item'; else section" [item]="area">
    </accordion-item>
  </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>

<ng-template #section let-name="name">
  <area-template [area]="area" class="{{ area.type }}">
  </area-template>
</ng-template>
```

It's throwing template phase error. please help

Comment: sample data of `areas`? Or you can share the code with StackBlitz

Comment: added sample data for areas

Comment: What is expected output and where is the code of `<accordion-item>`

Comment: So just move `mat-accordion` out of the `ngFor`..

Comment: Moved out of for loop now accordion is working, but the other contents are not displaying

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-accordion>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let area of areas" >
      <accordion-item *ngIf="area.type === 'accordion-item'"  [item]="area"></accordion-item>
   </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>

<ng-container *ngFor="let area of areas" #section>
   <ng-container *ngIf="!area.type === 'accordion-item'" #section>
      YOUR TEMPLATE
   </ng-container >
</ng-container >
```

Comment: accordion seems to be working, but `<ng-template #section>
  <template [area]="area" class="{{ area.type }}">
  </area-template>
</ng-template>`  it's throwing error as `area` in not defined in area-template

Comment: I've implemented, but it throws template phase error. I've updated my question

Comment: you have added let-name="name", that is for that particular case, you have to change name for the property you want

Comment: @user007 I've edited the answer so it doesn't use a ng-template anymore, since I suppose you don't want anything other than the accordion items inside the accordion. Just doing two loops is way simpler